# In R, the function seq(1,10) and seq(1:10) have same outputs and why there are different outputs for the function mean(1,10) and mean(1:10)?

Tags: r, function

I came across the following line of code

```
print(seq(1,10))
```

and

```
print(seq(1:10))
```

Both of the above lines gives the same output as

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Now I did for the `sum()` function

```
print(sum(1:10))
print(sum(1,10))
```

I got output as

```
[1] 55
[1] 11
```

My interpretation was correct in case of sum i.e; in case of colon(:) operator all numbers are added and result is printed as 55. In case of comma(,) operator,
1st and last numbers are added and result is printed 
But same thing I applied for `mean()` function

```
print(mean(1:10))
print(mean(1,10))
```

I got different outputs

```
[1] 5.5
[1] 1
```

But I expected same answer i.e; 5.5
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is not a difference between comma and colon, the difference is between the implementation of the function you are using. Better to look at the documentation of each function using `?function_name`.

Comment: Or rather `help("function_name")` such as `help(":")`.

Comment: @Roland there is no R documentation for comma operator. I tried that

Comment: I think it is not about the difference between comma and colon. It is the function of `seq()`. `sum(seq(1,10)) = sum(seq(1:10))`, `mean(seq(1, 10)) = mean(seq(1:10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between mean function and the seq function.

For seq, the function is

```
seq(from,to)
```

or you can use

```
seq(from:to)
```

you can refer below website for details:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq

while the mean function is,

```
mean(data,trim)
```

Data can be (1 until 10) and then you want to find mean; so you get 5.5 but when you insert mean(1,10). The value that you will get is only 1 because the data that you insert is only 1.
If you want to have the same value, you can use

```
mean(1:10)
```

you can refer below website for details:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mean

Comment: Why would you use `seq(1:10)` ? It is just `1:10`.